# How to store and update past RSSI values in iOS app?

Tags: ios

I've developed an iOS app that can read RSSI values from the surrounding [Estimote Beacons](http://estimote.com/). These RSSI values are fluctuating and to get a smooth value I need to use a filter. I am trying to use [Kalman filter] which needs some past RSSI values. Now, I am able to get the current RSSI values but cannot store them in database for filtration purpose. How can I store these RSSI values in database? I am using Objective-C for coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the line before you store the current RSSI value, take that value and store it in a similar variable called previousValue or something similar. Then you can do what you wish with it. As it's an NSNumber type, just invoke previousValue.intValue or similar to be able to store the type you need (or just store the NSNumber itself).

If you need more values just add each previousValue to an array variable. You shouldn't need that many previous values though for a Kalman filter, surely.

If you do need to store the data, CoreData or using SQLite directly are two possibilities. Or store the data in a UIDocument. If your question is really asking how to do these things, I would re-state your question. Otherwise there are countless resources for those techniques...

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and prompt information.I want to store RSSI values from 12 beacons and  want to get a smooth RSSI value from all the beacons(respectively) using Kalman Filter at any fixed place. More-precisely, I simply want to store and access the continuously fluctuating RSSI value in database and use it for filtration purpose. Is it possible using property list (.plist) file?

Comment: Ok, I see. So in fact you want 12 different results each filtered by Kalman filter and then a running average of those 12 smoothed values to get a positioning value. Right? Well, properties are probably not a good fit here. If your reason for persisting the data is to provide a positioning history, then go with a database alternative. In that case, your best option is CoreData, but SQLite is a lighter weight alternative. If you are not providing a history but still need to persist the data for some reason, perhaps a UIDocument-based approach would fit better.